# create empty jquery object based on a variable

Tags: jquery

I have the following code in a jQuery plugin:

```
 var $newItem = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
```

I need to replace the `'<li></li>'` part so the user can choose the element to use in the plugin configuration. Ex: div instead of li.

If I have a `var itemContainer = '<div>'` with the element type.
How can i use that variable in place of `'<li></li>'`?

I have tried this but doesnt work:

```
$(itemContainer, {})
```

Comment: `$(itemContainer).append(newForm);` ?

Comment: Should work... http://jsfiddle.net/dPyW9/

Comment: @tymeJV doesnt work becuase that way it maches all the li elements of my page. I want to create an empty element.

Comment: @Bruno-P If that is happening, then the value of `itemContainer` is `li`, not `<li>`. This isn't valid html, but it should demonstrate that the concept works: http://jsfiddle.net/6pJbX/

Comment: @JasonP Yes but I just want the user to add the element (li, or div) in the plugin configuration. Well I can concatenate the value with < > but that dont look very pretty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? Looks more flexible and easier:

```
var elem = "div";
$(document.createElement(elem)).text("hello world").appendTo("body");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8cVTZ/)

I'm not sure, but *maybe* oldIE will have problem if an not existing tag name is passed.